# Fixed header with scrolling content above?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a site for a family business and I'm putting in a fixed navigation bar, but I want the company logo and address (above the nav bar) to disappear when the user scrolls, while the nav bar stays in place. Here is the link so you can see what I'm talking about:
http://lindseymotors.com

I've tried using the `fixed` CSS attribute but it causes the address and phone number to disappear when viewed in landscape orientation for some reason. I know it's possible with javascript, but I'm hoping to avoid that and just use CSS.

A working example of what I'm going for can be seen at http://31dodge.com. Notice that it says Kernersville at the top, then there is a nav bar below that with several buttons (menu, location, phone, a car, etc.) - when you scroll, the Kernersville area disappears but the navigation area remains up top the whole time, and on the desktop version, the Kernersville logo gets much smaller. This is what I'm trying to achieve without javascript if possible, if not, I would appreciate some help there because my javascript efficiency isn't the best anymore.

I have changed the `fixed` attribute to `absolute` for the time being, so the problem isn't showing up right now and I'm thinking that once I get the scrolling header figured out it won't be an issue.

Comment: you've gotta use jquery/javascript for what you are looking for...

Comment: I'm not sure about avoiding JS since you need to detect when a user 'scrolled' which cannot be achieved with CSS.

Comment: The best you'll be able to do without JS is to make two navigations.  One is fixed to the top of the browser window with a z-index of 1, the other is absolutely positioned to the top of the body with a z-index of 2.  essentially, the scrolling navigation will hide the fixed navigation until the user scrolls past the scrolling nav

Comment: Anyone have a compact JS/jQuery solution?

Comment: Can you provide a bit html??

Comment: @danL you want to preserve the nav but hide its content when scrolling? with what porpoise?